# Compute the two-sided confidence interval for specific power

Tags: confidence-interval

Suppose I have a hypothesis test for
$H_0: est_{LCL} \le 0.4$ vs $H_1: est_{LCL} > 0.4$ where $est_{LCL}$ denotes the lower confidence limit for a two-sided $100(1-a)\%$ confidence interval for $est$  .

For a two-sided $100(1-a)\%$ confidence interval, the $est_{LCL}$ can be calculated as
$ est_{LCL} = est- z_{1-a/2}\sqrt{var(est)}$. Inversely, for a given $\hat{est}$ and its variance $\hat{var(est)}$, I can find the confidence interval to reject $H_0: est_{LCL} \le 0.4$ by calculating
$ z= (\hat{est}-0.4)/\sqrt{\hat{var(est)}}$ and the confidence interval level would be $(1-(1-z)*2)*100\%$.

If I understand it correctly, this inversely calculated confidence interval $\hat{est}$ will have 100% power to reject $H_0: est_{LCL} \le 0.4$. My question is how to calculate the confidence interval such like this to have specific power say 80% to reject $H_0: est_{LCL} \le 0.4$ for given $\hat{est}$ and its variance $\hat{var(est)}$?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to ask, because these aren't hypotheses that you have formulated.  By definition, a hypothesis concerns a *parameter,* not a confidence limit.  The conclusion of "100% power" is especially mysterious.  Could you please clarify what you're doing?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question.

Comment: That doesn't respond to my comment, though.  *Comparing a confidence limit to a number* is not a hypothesis.  Are you perhaps trying to conduct a two-sided test of equality of a mean with $0.4$?  If so, your remarks about 100% power remain incomprehensible.

Comment: My hypothesis is to test whether the lower confidence limit of an estimate (est) less or great a value (0.4). It doesn't matter what the estimate is. If we have an estimate and its variance, we can find its CI at any $\alpha$. But what I am interested is to find the lower confidence limit at given estimate and variance to reject a LCL at 0.4. I hope its helpful.

Comment: It would help not to call that a "hypothesis," because in a testing situation that term has a conventional meaning differing importantly from your use.  In order to define a power you *must* specify a hypothesis in the standard sense.  As an example, that might something of the form "If I want to test whether a mean equals $x$ and I know--or assume--the variance of the data, how large a sample do I need to have $y$% chance that the lower limit of a symmetric $1-\alpha$% confidence interval will exceed 0.4?" You need to tell us $x,$ $y,$ and the assumptions you are making.